# Adobe Flash CS6 Moving Anchor Points?

Tags: adobe-flash

first question here so hopefully it's okay. I've searched for how to do this everywhere online but I couldn't find anything.

I'm using flash CS6 and I have a shape. I want to animate it so that only one anchor point moves in the animation, not the entire shape. I have absolutely no idea how to do this, any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can animate simple morphing shapes using [shape tweens](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WS58E1E1A4-9296-4b75-AB74-D9D545892556.html). They can be unpredictable though, so for longer or more complicated movements it may help to split the shape up and only shape tween the areas which are changing.